# Gamelift Unity server build not running issue. InitSDK() was not called in time

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl, amazon-gamelift

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIjLq.png)

I'm encountering an issue while using Amazon GameLift to deploy a Unity-based game server. Specifically, I'm receiving the "SERVER_PROCESS_SDK_INITIALIZATION_TIMEOUT" error.

I've reviewed my server code, and I'm confident that InitSDK() is being called in the start method of the server init script. Despite this, I continue to encounter this error.

Details:

- I'm using the correct version of the GameLift SDK that matches my server build.
- The server log shows no exceptions or errors that might be delaying the InitSDK() call.
- The server startup time is within an acceptable range, so it should not be exceeding the initialization timeout.
- Resource provisioning for the server seems adequate.

I tried pushing several github project, but nothing work. The result is the same.

Comment: I dont know anything about gamelift, but, im guessing it  opens ports? does it talk to something on the internet to register its alive? it does say it  timed out - look at the logs, maybe they have a more specific answer?

Comment: The thing is build is running perfectly on local server. But it is not working on gamelift...

Comment: that still says firewall